# How to solve a filename conflict problem?

Tags: arcobjects, vba, vb.net

I use a procedure to remove and delete a feature layer with a certain name. Then, using another procedure which is called during the run time of the program (as the remove and delete procedure as well) I try to create a new feature layer which needs to have the same filename as that removed-deleted before. Unfortunatley, the program stops in the code line that tries to create the new feature layer. It is definetely because of the conflict between the previous and the new filename which are the same. How can I solve this problem?
Any help please?

Comment: Are you using [IDataset.Delete](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Delete_Method/00250000017r000000/) to delete the file(s) associated with the layer that is being removed?

Comment: @Kirk: Yes.I use the delete method of IDataset.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall let me guess - 'COMException'! Oh how I don't miss ArcObjects development

Comment: No I do not get any message. Simply, the program stops by highlighting the line I try to create (using Thiessen polygons GP) the new feature class that has the same name as that deleted some time before (during run-time).

Comment: Perhaps near your delete code maybe missing some Set variable = Nothing. This may have some handles open to the deleted Dataset. Ensuring all those variables are out of scope or set to Nothing will give the Garbage Collector the best chance to cleanup things so that you can recreate the feature layer.

Comment: I suppose that when a procedure or a function is called by another procedure then when the called procedure/function finish its job automatically cleans variables used by them. Is that right?